# Add information from multiple files into one file C++

Tags: c++, file, copy

I am trying to add the contents of multiple files over to another file, but I am having trouble.  It seems that every time I add the contents of one file, it overwrites the contents of the last file I added.  Here is my code:

```
  cout << "Enter Directory Location" << endl;
  string name;
  getline(cin, name);
  cout << "Directory: " << name << " Used" << endl;
  name += "/title";   

  int x = 1;  // I am assuming that the file number will simply start at 1
  int y;
  cout << "Enter Number of Files" << endl;
  cin >> y;  

  while(x <= y)
  {
        stringstream sstm;
    sstm << name << x;
    name = sstm.str();
    name += ".png";
    ifstream binfile(name.c_str(),ios::in | ios::binary);

        myfile << binfile.rdbuf();
    x++;    
  }
```

As always, I appreciate any help!

Comment: ios::append, perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `ios::app` to configure the file stream in "append" mode.

```
using namespace std;
ofstream foo ("foo.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

Comment: -1: The OP is appending to `myfile` which is an output stream and there is no `ios::append`.

Comment: Changed name of variable to neither `myFile` nor `binfile` to avoid obscuring the important bit.

Answer (score 1):

is it append needed in binfile, I think the problem is in the myfile, i dont see any declaration here, but I suppose it is ofstream, and there should be ios::append